# What unicode character I can use to "flag" a string?

Tags: javascript, html, json, string, unicode

I want to represent an object that has several text properties, every one representing the same text value but in different languages. In case the user modifies a single field, the other fields should be revised, and I'm thinking on adding a single Unicode character at the beginning of the string of the other fields, and then to check for fields that need attention, I just have to check the value at `obj.text_prop[0]`.

Which Unicode character can I use for this purpose? Ideally, it would be non-printable, supported in JS and JSON.

Comment: Please don't do this. Just store the flag elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Such flagging should be done some other way, at a protocol level other than character level. For example, consider as making each language version an object rather than just a string; the object could then have properties such as `needsAttention` in addition to the property that contains the string.

But in case you need to embed such information into a string, then you could use ZERO WIDTH SPACE U+200B. As such it means line break opportunity, but this should not disturb here. The main problem is probably that old versions of IE may display it as a small rectangle.

Alternatively, you could use a noncharacter code point such as U+FFFF, if you can make sure that the string is never sent anywhere from the program without removing this code point. As described in Ch. 16 of the Unicode Standard, [Special Areas and Format Characters](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch16.pdf), noncharacter code points are reserved for internal use in an application and should never be used in text interchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use strange characters in the beginning of the line. You can implement something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LocalizationSet(){};

    LocalizationSet.prototype.localizationItems = [];
    LocalizationSet.prototype.itemsNeedAttention = [];

    LocalizationSet.prototype.setLocalization = function(langId, text)
    {
        this.localizationItems[langId] = text;
        this.itemsNeedAttention[langId] = true;
    }

    LocalizationSet.prototype.getLocalization = function(langId)
    {
        return this.localizationItems[langId];
    }


    LocalizationSet.prototype.needsAttention = function(langId)
    {
        if(this.itemsNeedAttention[langId] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return this.itemsNeedAttention[langId];
    }

    LocalizationSet.prototype.unsetAttentionFlags = function()
    {
        for(var it in this.itemsNeedAttention)
        {
            this.itemsNeedAttention[it] = false;
        }
    }

    //Example
    var set = new LocalizationSet();
    set.setLocalization("en","Hello");
    set.setLocalization("de","Willkommen");

    alert(set.needsAttention("en"));
    alert(set.needsAttention("de"));

    set.unsetAttentionFlags();
    alert(set.needsAttention("en"));
    set.setLocalization("en","Hi");
    alert(set.needsAttention("en"));
    //Shows true,true,false,true
</script>
```